# git- Checkout multiple file from different commits

Tags: git, git-checkout

Let's say I have `fileA.py` and `fileB.py`, and I want to restore both of these file to a previous version using `git checkout <commit> <filename>`.

The issue I have is the versions I want to restore were committed in two different commits. Is there a way to restore both files using one command, or do I have to do each one on its own.

Comment: You must do each one on its own. (You can view both blobs with one command, using the `<rev>:<path>` syntax, but you'll still have to extract each one separately anyway.)

Comment: @Abdelrahman, you need different commit-hash for different file names, hence you will have to the above command for n times for n files.

Comment: @Abdelrahman, If commit-hash was same for the all files to checkout, then you should be looking for similarity between filenames so that you can target all the required files using `regex` in single command.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. This is what I suspected. Not a huge issue anyway

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with a single command. You can use a loop:

```
for x in "commit1 filea.py" "commit2 fileb.py"; do git checkout $x; done
```